# There is no public key available for the following key IDs: 7638D0442B90D010

Tags: ubuntu, debian, apt, public-key

I try to add the debian sid source on ubuntu 12.04 LTS. I have already installed debian-keyring debian-archive-keyring.

```
$ apt-cache search keyring | grep debian
debian-archive-keyring - GnuPG archive keys of the Debian archive
debian-keyring - GnuPG keys of Debian Developers
debian-ports-archive-keyring - GnuPG archive keys of the debian-ports archive
emdebian-archive-keyring - GnuPG archive keys for the emdebian repository
```

However, it still said one key is missing: 7638D0442B90D010. What did I miss?

```
#apt-key adv --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv-keys 7638D0442B90D010
Executing: gpg --ignore-time-conflict --no-options --no-default-keyring --secret-keyring /tmp/tmp.xxxxx --trustdb-name /etc/apt/trustdb.gpg --keyring /etc/apt/trusted.gpg --primary-keyring /etc/apt/trusted.gpg --keyring /etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d//debian-archive-squeeze-automatic.gpg --keyring /etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d//debian-archive-squeeze-stable.gpg --keyring /etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d//debian-archive-wheezy-automatic.gpg --keyring /etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d//debian-archive-wheezy-stable.gpg --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv-keys 7638D0442B90D010
gpg: requesting key 2B90D010 from hkp server keyserver.ubuntu.com
gpg: key 2B90D010: public key "Debian Archive Automatic Signing Key (8/jessie) <ftpmaster@debian.org>" imported
gpg: no ultimately trusted keys found
gpg: Total number processed: 1
gpg:               imported: 1  (RSA: 1)
```

It seems I only have debian squeeze and wheezy keys. How could I install keyring for sid?